# Android Studio: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: android-studio

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/pkg/lib/libgnustl_shared.so" not found**

I am getting this error when installing/Debugging-->Launching the app in android studio.
I am still helpless and crawling on google.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem. I am also facing the same issue. my question is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636329/dlopen-failed-error-while-transferring-application-to-virtual-device

Comment: Hi, it need to compile the native lib/project first if you are using any native lib, After that compile the main project.

Comment: what do you mean? I am using 3 native libs which i compiled on Netbeans. And those were compiled perfectly.

Comment: Means you have all the .so file for the libraries. Then build it in android Studio with main project it should work.