# Android Library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found

Tags: android, maven, android-ndk, android-library, dlopen

I had a build question, specifically using the Maven build environment. I am building an Android library using the Android NDK (r10e). I am building for Android 6.0 (API 23). Although after I use this library in my main project and drop it on my tablet, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libgnustl_shared.so" not found
```

My Application.mk is:

> APP_ABI := all
>
> APP_STL:=gnustl_shared
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

My maven file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myParent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.android</groupId>
        <version>1.05</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>myNativeLib</artifactId>

    <packaging>so</packaging>

    <name>testNativeLib</name>

    <properties>
        <android.ndk.args>V=1 -B NDK_DEBUG=1 -j8</android.ndk.args>
        <arch>armeabi-v7a armeabi</arch> <!-- TODO add more arch types -->
        <mavenAntrunPluginVersion>1.8</mavenAntrunPluginVersion>
        <includes.version>1.0.6</includes.version>
        <sonar.sources>src,pom.xml</sonar.sources>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-webdav</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-ndk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${project.artifactId}</target>
                    <finalLibraryName>${project.artifactId}</finalLibraryName>
                    <ndkPath>${android.ndk.path}</ndkPath>
                    <!-- so jenkins parameter -Dandroid.ndk.path actually works. -->
                    <applicationMakefile>src/main/cpp/Application.mk</applicationMakefile>
                    <makefile>src/main/cpp/Android.mk</makefile>
                    <architectures>${arch}</architectures>
                    <additionalCommandline>${android.ndk.args}</additionalCommandline>
                    <librariesOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/ndk-libs</librariesOutputDirectory>
                    <objectsOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/ndk-obj</objectsOutputDirectory>
                    <headerFilesDirectives>
                        <headerFilesDirective>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/cpp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**\/*.hpp</include>
                            </includes>
                        </headerFilesDirective>
                    </headerFilesDirectives>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- placeholder -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <android.ndk.args>V=1 -B -j8</android.ndk.args>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Now, this generates the .so that I want and throws it into my .m2 (repository) folder. I then go to my main project and it builds just fine. Its after I drop it on the tablet and start it (where it tries to loadLibrary) is where it fails. I have not seen anything on SO on this issue specifically in this setup. Closest thing I've seen is this dead thread:

[Android Studio: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666623/android-studio-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed)

which was not very helpful. Its important to note that this work on my Android 4.0 implementation (API 18). Just not on 6.0. Looking at the apk, I can see the .so in

```
lib\armeabi-v7a\testNativeLib.so
```

Any thoughts? I'm stuck here.

Comment: Or maybe if we have a way of adding the libgnustl_shared.so file to the libs folder. Is there a way to directly copy this over from the NDK? i.e. lib\armeabi-v7a\

Comment: NDK did probably copy this library to `${project.build.directory}/ndk-libs`

Answer (score 0):

Along with your library, the APK must include the STL runtime, in your case `libgnustl_shared.so`. if you only have it for **armeabi**, this could be an explanation of your crash.

Another difference is that, in API 18, you must load the STL library separately from Java, it didn't handle dependencies well back then.

BTW, is your library really named  `testNativeLib.so`? Without **`lib`** prefix it won't be properly installed.

Comment: no, sorry it is not really named this. I should of put lib before. Thanks. So how do I specify this as well?

Comment: Specify what? To begin with, let's check the contents of your APK: does it have the STL library? *(You can use any zip viewer for that)*

Comment: it does not have the libgnustl_shared.so library in my libs folder in the APK. Unless there is another area I'm missing to check?

Comment: If it's not in your APK, it could be that on your specific API 18 device this file can be found among system libraries, a vaguely remember such bug.

Comment: So it is then not in API 23? I can add it manually and it works, but I'm looking for a more automated solution

Comment: The STL runtime is not part of system. It was shipped on Note 4 as part of Sasmung's infamous bloatware, and was causing many troubles. The best practice is to have the version from your NDK packed in the APK. `ndk-build` takes care of this, so you only need to tweak your Maven to pack this file together with `libtestNativeLib.so`.

Comment: OK, do you know how to do that with Maven? I have the libtestNativeLib.so and I have what I need in maven to add it to the appropriate libs area, but I don't know how to pull from the NDK and add it alongside this lib via Maven.

Comment: `${project.build.directory}/ndk-libs` is the directory where you get your native library, isn't it? How you get it packed into the APK, I don't know. What you can do, find the relevant `libgnustl_shared.so` in your NDK and copy it to same directory manually. Hopefully, Maven will pack the two together.

Comment: So ${project.build.directory}/ndk-libs  is where everything gets put. It doesn't contain the libgnustl_shared.so library. I have copied manually to this location and it worked fine, but I need an automated solution.

Comment: If you put it into the .m2 repository once, it will stay there.

Comment: Yeah, doing this in maven though I am at a loss. Not sure if I can put 2 .so files in my .m2 area. I have the logic of getting the .so in my main project, I would just duplicate it for the extra lib. Just not sure how to get that shared lib into the .m2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183192/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-new-guy).

Answer (score 0):

Copy libs files to

> src/main/libs

point libs file in the app.gradle file

[image]